# How to Improve the Long Poll Capabilities Using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, apache, long-polling

I have implemented the long polling successfully using normal Apache server, PHP, AJAX and Javascript. I don't use the Jquery to communicate with the server.

The problem is that the Apache server capabilities are limited, the server is not able to serve more than 5 browser tabs.

I wonder if there is any customization for the Apache or for the PHP to make them handle more concurrent connections? Or if there is any new/smart technique to do that? What are the maximum threads can be handled by a robust web server specialized in long polling?

I am not interested in the Web Sockets because of the browsers compatibility. I need something easy and robust into PHP. What Facebook are doing? I wonder how can they handle all the dynamic updates for million of users! What products/techniques they use?

A sample of my code:

**srv_polling.php**

```
<?php
function getResults(){..... return result;}

// recursive function inside the server 
function hasResultChanged($old,$timeStart){

    // to avoid server timeout (in seconds) in case no change for results
    if(round(abs(time() - $timeStart) / 60*60,2) > 50)
        return;

    $new = getResults();

    if($new != $old)    // get back to browser
        return true;
    else{
        $old = getResults();
        sleep(2);
        return $hasResultChanged($old,$timeStart);

    }
}

$timeStart = time();
$old  = $getResults();
sleep(2);
$hasResultChanged($old,$timeStart);

?>

// Javascript code to be executed at browser end
alert('Result has changed');

// Send AJAX request again to same page(srv_polling.php):
ajax.call({......})
```

Thank you for your hints! Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in my project

```
public function getLPollData($user, $handlerName) {
    set_time_limit (600);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
    $counterEnd = (int)$_REQUEST["counterEnd"];
    $counterStart = (int)$_REQUEST["counterStart"];
    $this->expireNotifications($counterStart, $counterEnd);
    $secCount = IDLE_WAIT;
    do {
        sleep(IDLE_TIME);
        $updates = $this->fetchAllNotifications($counterEnd);
    } while (!$updates && ($secCount--)>0);

    if($updates){

    }

    header("HTTP/1.0 200");
    return sprintf ('{"time" : "%s", "counter" : "%d", start : %d, data : %s}'
            , date('d/m H:i:s'), $counterEnd,$counterStart,json_encode($updates));
}
```

Its combination of IDLE_WAIT & IDLE_TIME (10*3=~30 secs).

But i dont think your problem is on server side, if you are opening 5-6 connections from a browser, then remember each browser has limitation  on how many active connections it can have to some particular domain, at a time. try diff browser or better diff machines, max two tabs in one browser.